# ggplot grouped stacked barchart change tick labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that I want to create a grouped stacked barplot for.

```
df <- 
structure(list(value = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L), .Label = c("Q1_1", "Q1_2", "Q1_3", "Q1_4", "Q1_5", 
"Q2_1", "Q2_2", "Q2_3", "Q2_4", "Q2_5"), class = "factor"), 
    Freq = c(75L, 214L, 759L, 1788L, 512L, 934L, 918L, 701L, 
    300L, 495L, 526L, 917L, 959L, 554L, 392L, 121L, 335L, 654L, 
    856L, 1382L, 178L, 327L, 577L, 673L, 1593L, 744L, 841L, 876L, 
    597L, 290L, 787L, 1151L, 777L, 382L, 251L, 656L, 1253L, 869L, 
    406L, 164L, 586L, 1150L, 731L, 407L, 474L, 245L, 529L, 699L, 
    842L, 1033L), sq = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
    "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
    "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
    "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
    "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5"), mq = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1", 
    "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", 
    "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", 
    "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", 
    "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", 
    "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", 
    "Q2", "Q2"), tq = c("A1", 
    "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A1", 
    "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
    "A2", "A3", "A3", 
    "A3", "A3", 
    "A3", "A4", "A4", 
    "A4", "A4", "A4", "A6", "A6", 
    "A6", "A6", "A6", 
    "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A2", 
    "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
    "A3", "A3", 
    "A3", "A3", 
    "A3", "A4", "A4", 
    "A4", "A4", "A4", "A5", "A5", 
    "A5", "A5", "A5"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
r$> head(df)                                                                    
  value variable Freq sq mq tq
1     1     Q1_1   75  1 Q1 A1
2     2     Q1_1  214  1 Q1 A1
3     3     Q1_1  759  1 Q1 A1
4     4     Q1_1 1788  1 Q1 A1
5     5     Q1_1  512  1 Q1 A1
6     1     Q1_2  934  2 Q1 A2
```

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=mq, y= Freq, fill= value)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill=value) ,stat="identity") + facet_grid(.~sq)
```

Gives me this plot (which is almost what I want)
[image: plot output]

Now I'd like to have the x-axis tick labels to be whatever is in the `tq` column of my dataset. For every combination of `mq` and `sq` there is only one possible `tq` value.

Edit for clarity: `sq` is supposed to determine the "group", for each `mq` there should be one stacked bar (per group), and the label should be the corresponding unique entry in the `tq` column for that combination.

Comment: Why not just make one big graph with `aes(x = tq)`?

Comment: @CaptainHat Two reasons: a) multiple `mq`,`sq` combinations can have the same `tq` value, so directly plotting `tq` results in a wrong graph. b) I need the bars to be grouped as above..

Comment: Personally I would make a new variable of different `mq`/`sq` combinations, then make it an ordered factor for groupings. You can pass a function to the `labels` argument of `scale_x_discrete` which takes breaks as input and returns labels - I would just chuck a lookup table into that function to reassign the labels you want.

Comment: The thing that is tripping me up is that you say that every combination of mq and sq has only one possible tq. But (sq == 1 & mq == Q1) and (sq == 1 & mq == Q2) both have tq == A1. The labels are just supposed to be A1 twice?

Comment: @IanCampbell yes, A1 should be a label twice then... Think of `tq` as a non-injective, surjective function of `sq` and `mq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use `tidyr::unite` to make a combination of columns to make the x variable and use `scales = "free_x"` to remove empty columns from the facets:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  unite(comb, c(sq,mq,tq), sep = "-",remove = FALSE) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=comb, y= Freq, fill= value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=value) ,stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(.~sq, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

From here you can use a custom labeler function to get rid of the extraneous information in the x ticks:

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
  unite(comb, c(sq,mq,tq), sep = "-",remove = FALSE) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=comb, y= Freq, fill= value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=value) ,stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(.~sq, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x)str_remove(x,".*-")) + 
  labs(x = "Important X Variable")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations. Nice solution. I will delete my because it' s the same.

Comment: @TarJae This happens all the time, people come up with the same solution. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you Ian Campbell. Worked so hard today on this issue. Honestly your `scales = "free_x"` addition opened my eyes. Thank you. Then I will leave the answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- df %>%  
  unite(mq_tq, c("mq", "tq"), remove=FALSE)


ggplot(df, aes(x=mq_tq, y= Freq, fill= value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=value) ,stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(.~sq, scales = "free_x")  
  scale_x_discrete( name="")
```

[image]